# hover on one element change the background img of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried using javascript to change the background img of  by hovering on .

But the javascript only works on the first

```js
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9385da4a3618cdc385bd49fe3d951b78?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)";
}, false);
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "";
}, false);

document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "url(https://image.ibb.co/nOtP2U/2.png)";
}, false);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = "";
}, false);
```

```css
 #bg { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d5d2cf334288dd34914b29fd5d941e56?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
}
```

```html
<a id="a" href="" > A</a>

<br></br>

<a id="b" href="" > B</a>

<br></br>

<a id="c" href="" > C</a>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6YEAG/109/) (or see in snippet)

Comment: `getElementByI9858d("a")`?

Comment: `</br>` doesn't exist.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms i think that is a typo user made. Also, the question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Fix the typos and it seems to work fine. This is why you should use your developer console. The error message was clear as day.

Comment: @epascarello I added that to an answer

Comment: Timothy Cai, you may want to read through your code before posting it to StackOverflow. Out of experience, some people get very annoyed when people post issues that are easily solvable. I'm fine with it, but meh.

Comment: Imo should just be closed as a typo error since it will add no value to future readers.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms My apologies, I am new here so I am not familiar with the rules. I will do it next time.

Comment: @TimothyCai Yeah, it's not a super big problem, but people sometimes get annoyed. I'm personally fine with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with your syntax. A quick look at the console can show you errors that you're getting with your code.

`getElementByI9858d` isn't a valid method, instead, you need to use `getElementById`

See revised code:

```js
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage =
    "url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9385da4a3618cdc385bd49fe3d951b78?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)";
}, false);
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage =
    "";
}, false);



document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage =
    "url(https://image.ibb.co/nOtP2U/2.png)";
}, false);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage =
    "";
}, false);
```

```css
#bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d5d2cf334288dd34914b29fd5d941e56?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
}
```

```html
<a id="a" href=""> A</a>

<br /><br />

<a id="b" href=""> B</a>

<br /><br />

<a id="c" href=""> C</a>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few key issues with your code. For example:

```
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
   document.getElementBy####Id("bg").style.backgroundImage= //Should be getElementById, not getElementBy####Id
   "";
}, false);
```

Also, there are a few little issues with things being typed too quickly. I changed it, and it worked. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From your code just replace

```
 getElementByI9858d("a").addEventListener("mouseout",
```

to

```
getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseout",
```

in both "mouseout" event and you can get the result you required.